# How can I use Phaser inside loop's server request?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My code is like:

```
someFunction() {

        // countdownlatch is set up here

        for (i = 0; i<cyclesCount; i++) {
            //request is sending

            someServerRequest.executeWithListener(new CustomListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Integer response) {
                    arraylist.add(response);
                }
            });
        }

        //countdownlatch waits here
        //do something with arraylist

    }
```

CountDownLatch helps to wait for the loop, but every server request inside it is done in separate thread. So I get responses in random order, which is not suitable for me.

I tried using Phaser and CountDownLatch in different ways, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (for example) make a `Result` class, and add instances of *that* to an `ArrayList`.  For example:

```
private static class Result {
    private final int resultNumber;
    private final Integer response;

    private Result(final int resultNumber, final Integer response) {
        this.resultNumber = resultNumber;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

And then have

```
for (i = 0; i < cyclesCount; i++) {
    someServerRequest.executeWithListener(new CustomListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Integer response) {
            arrayList.add(new Result(i, response));
        }
    });
}
```

You can then sort the list based on the `resultNumber` (and map it to just a list of the `responses` if you need to), or make `Result implements Comparable<Result>` and then just use natural sorting from there.

Additionally: `ArrayList` isn't thread safe (just going by the name of your variable).  I'd recommend `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` if you're using this in actual production code.